# How can I better work coffee into my morning routine

Tags: french-press

I am a pretty lazy person and sometimes it takes me awhile to get around to making coffee. I have a french press and I grind my own coffee so it takes a little longer. What are some simple ways I can speed up my coffee making process or better work it into my morning routine without sacrificing quality?

Comment: Can you clarify if you're looking for new brewing methods or if you're looking for streamlining your existing system?

Comment: You can try to get your hands on one of these http://www.joshrenoufdesign.com/new-gallery-5/
You have hot coffee ready as soon as you wake up, unless you snooze a lot :)

Comment: @schvaba Ok, you just blew my mind!

Comment: You should sign up, maybe it speeds up the development :)

Answer (score 5):

I had a similar problem and I ended with [`aeropress`](https://coffee.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/aeropress). To speed up the process I use pre-grinded coffee which I store in the fridge. Once you press the coffee, the cleanup is very fast.

Comment: Cleanup is very fast with the aeropress

Answer (score 5):

I am pretty ineffective before my first cup, and my family doesn't want to hear anything since I'm the first one up. So I make it easier on myself and them:

- grind enough for the first cup the night before. Store grounds at room temperature, not in the fridge. This is a slight tradeoff in quality. If you don't need silence, then just have the beans ready to grind.
- wash out the press and leave it ready
- prep the water (I use a hot water dispenser built in to my sink)
- and your cup
- do it exactly the same way every day so you don't have to think or decide

Answer (score 0):

Though now deleted, I most prefer @EdChum's comment: brew a pot of [cold-brew](/questions/tagged/cold-brew) the night before! Pour and enjoy. Cannot get easier or tastier.

For nearly instant hot coffee, use *instant coffee powder*. Mix boiled water with coffee powder. Attempt to drink while you prepare a better-tasting cup of coffee. See tag [instant](/questions/tagged/instant).

For fast, automatic laziness -- yielding a quick, easy cup of passable coffee -- you can't beat pod-based automatic machines. Fill the pitcher with water, insert pod, press button... done. The only thing to mess up could be forgetting to place a coffee cup below the spigot. Clean-up is practically non-existent. I personally find the quality of this coffee to be low and unsatisfying.

Otherwise, streamline your French Press routine:

1. Start your water boiling. Go about other business for a few minutes (or stare at the wall if other business is impossible before coffee).
2. When the water has boiled, grind your coffee and put it in your сafetière (French Press). Add water; submerge coffee. Wait.
3. Press and drink.
4. Begin clean-up: dump grounds into compost and allow to dry on its own (a few hours).
5. Shake out dried coffee and rinse; repeat as necessary.

Commentary:

- This permits really only 3 steps of brewing: boil, mix, press. This is about as simple as possible. By grinding after boiling, this minimizes the amount of time between grind and brew (crucial minutes!) and minimizes the overhead of manual interaction.
- By using the multi-step clean-up process that I describe, this maximizes efficiency: get most of the coffee out by shaking when still wet (just brewed). Allow to dry on its own, and the rest of the coffee grounds will come out easily. A simple rinse is enough to get most of the remnants out without clogging a sink drain.

Long live manual coffee production methods!  See other guides from [Coffee Geek](http://coffeegeek.com/guides/presspot), [Blue Bottle](https://bluebottlecoffee.com/preparation-guides/french-press), and [How To Brew Coffee](http://www.howtobrewcoffee.com/French.htm) -- I prefer a simpler approach that I describe than all of those.

Comment: "Attempt to drink," that is really funny. I have never tried instant coffee but I have heard it is not that good.